# JavaScript: Regex match this string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check using regex that a string matches this format:

```
http://site.com/users/1
```

e.g. a matching string is `http://stackoverflow.com/users/587532` and `http://stackoverflow.com/users/587532/umar` should be not matching.

but I don't know the regex code to do this.

Comment: http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=a61b9ff5-3048-80a9-ef09c0a7f1e9fbd3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://([^/]+)/users/(\d+)`

The first capture group gives you the site's name, the second gives you the user number.

If you need to escape the `/` characters, just use `\/`:

`http:\/\/([^\/]+)\/users\/(\d+)`

Comment: `/http:\/\/([^\/]+)\/users\/(\d+)$/g`

Comment: I would add a ^ and $ to make sure you don't match a partial (your regex still matches the case where the '/umar' is behind the url, it just doens't include it in it's match.

Comment: @umar, the `$` at the end of the regex makes the `/g` modifier superfluous.